# Heavy Blade Opportunity against two targets

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

The Heavy Blade Opportunity feat (PHB) lets a character use any of their at-will powers for their opportunity attacks.

Opportunity attacks, on the other hand, target the triggering creature.

What happens when using an at-will power that mandates to target two different attacks, such as the tempest-fighter power Dual Strike (MP)?
Is the second attack wasted because you can only target the triggerer? Or does it let you target a second, non-triggering enemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dual Strike power does not target two different enemies. It targets a single enemy (causing no conflict with the usual targeting of attacks of opportunity) and then, as an effect, mandates you to perform a secondary attack against a different target. This second attack is separated from the attack of opportunity and does not need to follow its rules.

Comment: Are you talking about the ranger at-will or the fighter at-will? The ranger and fighter both have at-wills that attack twice, but because the fighter is a defender their at-will explicitly requires you to attack two different targets, while the ranger one allows focus fire.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I was talking about the fighter at will (the ranger's is Twin Stike). Due to the unerrataed Dual Strike only targeting a single creature (attacking it twice) and a bad writeup in the character sheet of the player using Dual Strike, I gathered that its target line was "two different creatures", while it is not.

Comment: The errata makes it *quite* clear that it targets two different creatures.

Comment: @ObliviousSage yes, but my player wrote on his sheet "target: two different creatures" when in reality it is "Target: one creature; Effect: make a secondary attack; Secondary target. a different creature." Quite the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Specific rules override general rules, so you'd follow the text of the At-Will that replaces your regular Attack of Opportunity.

Comment: "Specific ovverides general" brings us from "You make a melee basic attack against the triggering enemy" to "You use an at-will [weapon] power that uses an heavy blade against the triggering enemy" (and ensures that the two rules don't conflict), but the problem still remains. By the way I have found that the problem never existed to begin with, and I will write an answer to explain why.